# Unable to Parse this RDF/XML since System.Xml was unable to parse the document

Tags: namespaces, rdf, system.xml, dotnetrdf

I'am using .Net RDF library to make some sparql query on RDF files.
but when I tried to load the RDF file to C# .Net RDFlibrary.

The error is:

> Unable to Parse this RDF/XML since `System.Xml` was unable to parse
>   the document, see Inner Exception for details

My RDF file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [<!ENTITY rdf 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'>
<!ENTITY rdfs 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#'>
<!ENTITY xsd 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#'>]>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" 
         xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
         xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:dnr="http://www.dotnetrdf.org/configuration#"
         xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace#"
         xml:base="http://www.example.org/">

  <rdf:Description rdf:about="Fadi">
    <ns0:eat xmlns:ns0="http://example.org/">Apple</ns0:eat>
    <xml:startTime>00:01:38</xml:startTime>
    <xml:endTime>00:01:39</xml:endTime>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

and the statement to load:

```
Graph myGraph = new Graph();
FileLoader.Load(myGraph, "C:\\Users\\hasoOn\\Desktop\\tt.rdf");
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? - and why I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually look at the Inner Exception as the exception messages tells you to?  That would contain the `XmlException` that was produced and would tell you exactly what is wrong with your RDF/XML including positional information i.e. where in the file the error is.

In your case your problem happens to be that you have defined the `rdf` namespace twice on the same element i.e. you have two `xmlns:rdf` attributes on your root `rdf:RDF` element which makes your XML illegal.

If you remove that then it will be valid XML however it will still fail to parse in dotNetRDF because you have used the properties `xml:startTime` and `xml:endTime` without defining the `xml` namespace.  I guess dotNetRDF should probably allow those because `xml:` is implicitly defined in XML though using the `xml` namespace for anything other than XML syntax itself is generally a very bad idea and a symptom of bad data modeling.

Comment: The Namespace URI for the given Prefix 'xml' is not known by the in-scope NamespaceMapper.  Did you forget to define a namespace for this prefix?

how can i solve the problem?

Comment: You should not be using the `xml` namespace for properties in your RDF (*NB* this happens to also highlight a bug that dotNetRDF should allow this since `xml` should be implicitly defined for RDF/XML).  
As I said in the end of my answer it is bad practice to use the `xml` namespace for your data modeling.  The `xml` namespace should only be used for XML specific stuff i.e. setting the Base URI and not for your actual data

Comment: Bug in dotNetRDF filed as CORE-358 (http://dotnetrdf.org/tracker/Issues/IssueDetail.aspx?id=358)

Comment: CORE-358 now fixed in default